# Find the volume in the first octant bounded by parabolic cylinders $z=9-x^2$ and $x=3-y^2$

Tags: integration

After solving by double integration method I am getting the answer $\frac{486 \sqrt3}{35}$, which seems to be wrong. The answer given for this question is $\frac{102 \sqrt3}{35}$. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you provide the source of the answer (Book, exam paper etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing ourselves in the first octant, we get the following three constraints: $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $z \geq 0$.

[image: Graph of the parabolic cylinders]

Using the expressions of the coordinates, we find the following integration boundaries for $y: 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{3}$.

We can now compute the volume as a triple integral:

$V = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{0}^{3-y^2} \int_{0}^{9-x^2} 1 \, dz \, dy \, dx = \frac{486 \sqrt{3}}{35}.$

I am having a hard time understanding where the $\pi$ is coming from and why the provided answer is not this one.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Note that the volume is a stack of rectangle sheets of the size $\sqrt{3-x}$ by $9-x^2$ along the $x$-direction, and can be obtained with the single integral,

$$V = \int_0^3 \sqrt{3-x}\cdot(9-x^2)dx=\frac{486\sqrt3}{35}$$

Comment: I subbed $3-x=a$, then $$V=\int_0^3\sqrt{a}.(6a-a^2)da = \frac{108\sqrt{3}}{35}$$. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @gemspark - $\int_0^3 ( 6a^{3/2}-a^{5/2})da = \frac{108\sqrt3}5- \frac{54\sqrt3}7=\frac{486\sqrt3}{35}$